# Vue - Unable to Pass Data From Component to Parent with $emit Event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

[Pass data from child to parent in Vuejs (is it so complicated?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43334796/pass-data-from-child-to-parent-in-vuejs-is-it-so-complicated)

[Can't pass data from children to parent component with emit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42670233/cant-pass-data-from-children-to-parent-component-with-emit)

[$emit an event from child to parent component Vue 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303474/emit-an-event-from-child-to-parent-component-vue-2)

I've looked through the posts above and the Vue documentation. From what I can see, I'm doing everything right, but it's still not working.

I've included my code but I'm afraid that I'm unable to a reproduction with a stack snippet. A working reproduction can be found here on this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-sosrr?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FButtons.vue)

---

### Buttons.vue

I've noted below under the `navigateTo()` function that my console confirms that the function on the component is getting the correct value, but I'm not sure that the value is being properly emitted by the component or received by the parent.

```
<template>
  <div class="navigation section columns">
    <div class="container column has-text-centered" v-for="button in navigation" :key="button.text">
      <button class="button is-primary" @click="navigateTo(button)" type="button">{{ button.text }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "Buttons",
  props: {
    text: String,
    dest: String
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    navigateTo(button) {
      // This console log correctly outputs "button dest 2"(or whatever the button value is)
      console.log("button dest", button.dest);
      this.$emit("navigate", button.dest);
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      navigation: [
        { text: "North", dest: "2" },
        { text: "East", dest: "3" },
        { text: "South", dest: "4" },
        { text: "West", dest: "5" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

### App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <scene @navigate="navigateTo"></scene>
    <buttons></buttons>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Scene from "./components/Scene.vue";
import Buttons from "./components/Buttons.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  methods: {
    navigateTo(dest) {
      console.log('received value', dest);
      this.selectedScene = dest;
    }
  },
  components: {
    Scene,
    Buttons
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: The component emitting the event is the button and you are listening to the event on the scene component

Comment: You're setting up the '@navigate' event handler in the `<scene >` component, yet the `navigate` event is being fired from `<button>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The component emitting the event is the button and you are listening to the event on the scene component:

Change your App.vue like this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <scene ></scene>
    <buttons @navigate="navigateTo" ></buttons>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Scene from "./components/Scene.vue";
import Buttons from "./components/Buttons.vue";

export default {
  name: "app",
  methods: {
    navigateTo(dest) {
      console.log('received value', dest);
      this.selectedScene = dest;
    }
  },
  components: {
    Scene,
    Buttons
  }
};
</script>
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Comment: by the way I dont see any usage of the `this.selectedScene ` in your code so I guess that you omitted some ...

Comment: Actually `this.selectedScene` is in another component so obviously I'll need to correct that. thanks!